# How can I create a list of dataframes or dictionary of dataframes in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe, but I want to convert this either into a list of dataframes or a dictionary of dataframes.

How can I go about this if I want to use a certain columns values as the keys?

For what it's worth, I can convert everything into tuples by doing `df.collect()`

I'm not able to find this anywhere else online, so was hoping someone on Stack Overflow might know how to do this.

Comment: `a list of dataframes `??? what do you mean? `[df1, df2...]`?

Comment: Hi Lamanus, yes exactly that. A few people mentioned they did on PySpark but they didn't show how they did it.